# How to dynamically choose a Virtual Warehouse Based on the data, in S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-ingestion, data-lake

*Hello All, i have been pondering on the following requirement, where i would like to increase the warehouse, size based on the File Size, in the S3.*

```
0 MB to 1024 MB -> Small Warehouse
1025 MB to 10250 MB (1+Gb to 10Gb) -> Medium Warehouse
10251 MB to 5TB (10Gb - 5TB) --> Which would be, S3 Object Max Storage File. 
(Large Warehouse)
```

*So, is there any way to programatically, perform these tasks, i.e
i knew that we could write a snow procedure, in JS and iterate as required, based on the source file size, but just wanted to know, is there any other way around !*

Comment: Just want to point out that loading files greater than 100gb is not recommended. You can refer to this link for file sizing best practices and limitations. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html

Comment: Are you looking for a non-programmatically solution or one that doesn't use JS?

Comment: pardon.me for the late reply, i would like to programatically, size and resize the warehouse based on the source,data file size. And would like to use JS though 1

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than writing a stored procedure, or Snowscript block.

**More important point is, using a larger warehouse on a single file will NOT improve the performance.** The nodes/servers in your warehouse will wait idle (at least when reading the file).

So you shouldn't just focus on the size of the file, you should also consider the number of files to ingest/read when choosing the warehouse size.

Comment: So, it seems like a bit challenging problem, But im thinking in this way,  a) getting total number of bytes of a bucket, and number of files present. b) If it meets my above requirements, i will then select the warehouse based on it.

Comment: yes you can write a stored procedure to do this